# Django Admin behaves weirdly

Tags: python, css, django, django-rest-framework

I have this Django app running perfectly but sometimes Django Admin works oddly, because If I click on any model, instead of taking me to the list of registries in that model, It takes me to the same model list but with a weird css.

Here is the picture of the normal model list
[image]

Here is the picture after clicking any model
[image]

I can't add information to models or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a few days ago. What solved the problem for me was re-collecting the statics:

```
(env)$python manage.py collectstatic
```

and then force relad (`ctrl` + `F5`) the django admin site.